# Finding the area of a spiral equation

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to solve this problem:

> Find the area of the region delimited by a spiral $r = \frac{4\theta}{3}, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, and with x-axis positive. The region resembles a snail shell. (Answer.: $\frac{64\pi^3}{27}$)

My try:

I made two double integrals:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{\frac{4\theta}{3}} r\;dr d\theta + \int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{4\theta}{3}} r\;dr d\theta \\ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{8}{9}\theta^2 \; d\theta + \int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi} \frac{8}{9}\theta^2 \; d\theta \\ \frac{8}{9} \left[\left.\frac{\theta^3}{3}\right|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} + \left.\frac{\theta^3}{3}\right|_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi}\right] \\ \frac{8}{9} \left[\frac{\pi^3}{24} + \frac{8\pi^3}{3} - \frac{27\pi^3}{24} \right] = \frac{38\pi^3}{27}$$

I don't understand what is wrong. I don't get the right answer.

Comment: The given answer is for $0$ to $2\pi$ and not just for positive $x$.

Comment: @MathLover So, the question is wrong?

Comment: The problem is poorly stated: the given answer is for the entire area enclosed by the spiral _and_ the positive $ \ x-$axis (take a look at a graph).  So you just want to integrate over $ \ \theta \ $ from $ \ 0 \ $ to $ \ 2\pi \ \ . $

Comment: @MatheusSousa it depends on how one reads it. The problem is not stated clearly. Based on the calculation they have done, it seems they mean $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ with $\theta$ being measured between the radial line from the origin and positive x-axis.